# docker cannot start container on google cloud platform

Tags: docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

Can't start docker container with:

```
docker start tensorflow1
```

I use docker logs tensorflow1 ,it says:

```
[E 07:38:37.008 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/kernels/1e380902-1791-4e30-9f72-cea20d1d41b3/restart (64.64.108.69) 62117.82ms referer=http://35.221.176.13:8888/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb
[I 07:39:07.783 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 86555bd9-460a-419d-9402-def226ff4fc2
[I 07:40:12.105 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled2.ipynb

  sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1408, in init_webapp
self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen
sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets
sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

what's the problem ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't enough information in this question.  For example, you are starting a container called "tensorflow1" ... what is that?  Where did it come from?  I next get the suspicion that the docker images is running an iPython notebook ... since that is itself an application ... without knowing what is in it and which statement it is failing at ... there isn't much to go on.

Comment: you are right, there are several jupyter notebook in there, and I want to open these notebook in browser then run some program.

Answer (score 0):

After remove all running containers, I rebuilt container again and then succeeded. I think the reason for my problem is other container running with the same address and the same port